Kubernetes self managed cluster connection
I have managed to run Kubernetes cluster within my local network consisting if several nodes running as multipass instances and several devices. I am using cilium for the networking. What I am trying to achieve is to connect outside sourced node located in different network, but I have no idea how to proxy the nodes IP address, as within the node list it’s InternalIP is the nodes local IP address not a public.
